# Determinant of orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The Wikipedia page on orthogonal transformation says:

> In linear algebra, an orthogonal transformation is a linear transformation T : V → V on a real inner product space V, that preserves the inner product. That is, for each pair u, v of elements of V, we have
>
> $$\langle u,v\rangle =\langle Tu,Tv\rangle$$

Just given this definition, is it possible to prove that orthogonal transformations can only have $\pm 1$ determinant? I know the proof for orthogonal *matrices* but not for this general definition of orthogonal transformation. Or could someone tell me how to show that the matrix representation (with respect to an orthonormal basis) of an orthogonal transformation is an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: The determinant of a transformation is an invariant, hence equal to the determinant of its matrix relative to any basis.

Comment: @GReyes Well, how do we know that matrices corresponding to this transformation are the orthogonal matrices?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the matrix of $T$ in some basis. Then $T(u)=Au$ and $T(v)=Av$ where the $u$ and the $v$ in the right hand sides are not the vectors but the columns of their coordinates. Then $\langle u,v\rangle= \langle Au,Av\rangle$ for all $u$ and $v$. This is equivalent to $\langle u,v\rangle= \langle u,A^TAv\rangle$ where $A^T$ is the transpose. Given that $u$ is arbitrary, you conclude $A^TAv=v$ for all $v$, and given that $v$ is arbitrary, you conclude that $A^TA=Id$, which is the definition of orthogonal matrix.